# How to switch between v-html and insert as plain text in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm looking to toggle between v-html and insert as plain text in vue.js v2. So far I have this

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <h2 v-html="html ? text : undefined">{{html ? '' : text}}</h2>
  <button @click="toggle">
    switch
  </button>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text:"Hello<br/>World",
    html:false
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(){
        this.html = !this.html;
    }
  }
})
```

but this doesn't work when `html` is false. How can I get this to work? I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to repeat `<h2>` twice using a `v-else`. Preferably, if I can do it with just the 1 `<h2>` tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `v-bind` with the `prop` modifier.  [see docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text:"Hello<br/>World",
    html:false
  },
  computed: {
    headingProps() {
      return this.html ? { innerHTML: this.text } : { innerText: this.text } ;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(){
        this.html = !this.html;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2 v-bind.prop="headingProps"></h2>
  <button @click="toggle">
    switch
  </button>
</div>
```